# Is it really to catch the intent which is explicitly sended to one app from service in another?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have the following problem:

Intent is sent using the сonsole utility "am":
am startservice -a my_action -n com.test.one_app/.service.one_app_service

I need to catch this explicit intent from other (my) app.
Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because this is not a broadcast and it is not targeting the other app.